# Do Loki's illusions fool the sense of smell?

Tags: marvel, comics, loki

Loki has the ability to create illusions, most commonly copies of himself, that are visually indistinguishable from the original. However, if you try to touch them (or tackle them), you'll find that they are not solid, so the sense of touch is not part of the illusion.

What about the sense of smell? I ask because in *[Lego Marvel Super Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Marvel_Super_Heroes)*, there is a level where a number of superheroes get transported to Asgard to fight Loki. At various points, Loki creates duplicates of himself, and the way to progress is to use Wolverine's heightened senses to find the real one. Given that you often hear Wolverine sniffing, I presume that he's smelling out the real one because the illusions don't have a scent.

In mainline comics (i.e. Earth-616 or whatever it calls itself these days), do Loki's illusions fool the sense of smell? Would someone like Wolverine be able to sniff out the real Loki because the illusions don't have a scent?

Comment: Are you asking about Earth-616 specifically, because otherwise I'm sure the answer is, it depends.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, that's what I meant by "In mainline comics (i.e. Earth-616 or whatever it calls itself these days)". Is there a better way that I could phrase that?

Comment: Maybe I got thrown off by the phrase "mainline comics"... Loki has been featuring in comics for as long as I can remember (long before there was Earth-616), and I really wouldn't know which of these you would count as mainline, so I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not Wolverine's, no.

In *Wolverine: Infinity Watch* #1 (2019), Logan goes back to the Mansion after his complicated recent rebirth, and he doesn't have to knock - Jean knows he's here and opens the door to him. They hug, and while Logan's nose is in her hair, he realizes something's not right, and it turns out the whole thing is Loki's doing.

Granted there's no "sniffing" onomatopoea, but this is Wolverine, and given where his nose was, what else could it be than scent?

[image: Wolverine kills a Jean illusion] [image: fades out to Loki's doing]

Comment: So if Loki got stabbed, does that mean he gave Wolverine a hug?

Comment: @Thunderforge considering the sheer amount of WTFness _Infinity Watch_ brings, that's not even the most unexpected thing there was :-)